# The exception contained within MappableContainerException

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

Hi I am getting below exception in my webservice code could any one help in this

```
Jun 28, 2012 8:49:46 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException  
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.toro.utility.tenantconfig.DBManager  
    at com.ibm.toro.utility.tenantconfig.TenantConfigDB.getAllHotwords(TenantConfigDB.java:88)  
    at com.ibm.toro.utility.tenantconfig.TenantConfigDB.getAnalysisConf(TenantConfigDB.java:99)  
    at com.ibm.toro.utility.tenantconfig.GetTenantConfig.getTenantConfig(GetTenantConfig.java:58)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)  
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing something on the classpath. The exception you need to fix is the NoClassDefFoundException from TenantConfigDB.getAllHotwords(). MappableContainerException is just a wrapper exception that Jersey uses if the underlying code threw something that is not mappable to a response (in this case it is the NoClassDefFoundException). Seems some dependency of DBManager class cannot be loaded as it is not on the classpath.

Comment: I am getting same issue. I have a project(HibPro) which is using Hibernate to interact with database. other project(RestService) has services. one more project(clientTest) is used to test. HibPro has some method I want to call from RestService. could you please help what is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

i was doing a rest service calling an mq, what solved the issue for me was adding the .jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Strange that the same solution worked for me as well, any idea about the root cause of the error and the solution though?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you initiate an object with `new` and try to print or do anything with it. Below is the example that throws the stack overflow error:

```
JSONObject outerMostObj = new JSONObject();
outerMostObj.put("authFailure", outerMostObj);
System.out.println("Rretrun vaklueeee" + outerMostObj);
```

To resolve -> You need to assign proper value for the object and print or do whatever you want. Simple! :)

```
JSONObject outerMostObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject outerMostObj = fetch.getJSONValue(); //added this one
outerMostObj.put("authFailure", outerMostObj);
System.out.println("Rretrun vaklueeee" + outerMostObj);
```